# Какая форма слова правильная?

Tags: словосочетания, дефис, точное-словоупотребление

Теоретическо-практическое занятие или теоретико-практическое?

Answer (score 2):

Смотря что мы имеем в виду:

```
Теоретическо-практическое = Теоретически практическое
Практическо-теоретическое = Практически теоретическое
Практико-теоретическое = Практическое, в перемешку теоретическое 
Теоретико-практическое = Теоретическое, в перемешку практическое
```